# Excel 2016- Get & Transform does not work

Tags: .net, excel, odac

when I go to Data -> New Query -> From Database; no matter what database I select, nothing happens

On the first attempt a message on the bottom right says: "Connecting to .NET framework", but nothing happens after
 What is wrong?

edit: I noticed that my Outlook is affected. I can open it and view emails, but attempts to create a new email crashes it.

Comment: Honest suggestion, first check your computer for viruses.

Comment: Done, no viruses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repairing Office & reinstalling the ODAC seemed to fix everything.